# How to call a controller method from an action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm new in CakepHP and I want to use a method (that returns a value) in an action in CakePHP 3. Sort of like this:

```
public function specify(){
       if(isObject1){
     // do something}
 }
private isObject1($objname){
 return true;
}
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CakePHP is PHP

The way to call a method from another method of the same class is the same as with any php project using objects - by using `$this`:

```
public function specify() {
    $something = 'define this';
    if($this->isObject1($something)) {
        // do something
    }
}

private function isObject1($objname) {
     return true;
}
```

There's more info on how to use objects in [The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @AD7six suggests adding a method within the controller which is not right if it is not going to be used as an action.

I think you should consider creating classes under vendor and including them in your controller and calling your class/method. The convention is vendor/$author/$package. You can either autoload them with composer or use a require call to include your file.  If you don't want to create a class and just want to have functions, that can be done too.

Do take a look at cakephp's [loading vendor files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files) section.

Comment: `which is not right if it is not going to be used as an action.` untrue; Also, it's simply the code from the question.

Comment: if you please explain  your answer using example code?